# how to edit local notifications in iphone sdk objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, uilocalnotification

I am working on a dummy project in xcode 6 and creating local notifications. I have created and deleted these local notifications.Now I want to edit a particular notification.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so, show us some code so we can better help you. Read more about [how to ask a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change an already scheduled notification.

You will have to cancel, and re-create it with the new data you need.

You can ask the current scheduled `UILocalNotifications`:

```
NSArray *scheduledNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
```

Loop the array and do a check if its the notification you need to change:

```
for (UILocalNotification *notification in scheduledNotifications)
{
    //Get the ID you set when creating the notification
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    NSNumber *someValueYouGaveWhenCreatingCouldBeAnIdentifierOfAnObject = [userInfo objectForKey:@"someKey"];

    if (someValueYouGaveWhenCreatingCouldBeAnIdentifierOfAnObject == someCheckYouHaveToDoHere)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
        //Re-create the localnotification with new data and the someValueYouGaveWhenCreatingCouldBeAnIdentifierOfAnObject

        break;
    }
}
```